# How do I change the background colour and foreground colour using a button in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

So what I am trying to do is create a theme picker for my application

For example, the user could click on a the Green/Black button and it would change every widgets background to Black and it would change every widgets foreground to Green. Then they could click the Red/White button and it would do the same thing but change every widgets background to White and every widgets foreground to Red.

```
# Imports the tkinter library.
from tkinter import *
from tkmacosx import Button

# Pillow is a improved verison of PIL, stands for Python Image Library. Allows you to import image types like .jpg and .png
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

# Imports messagebox module from tkinter library.
from tkinter import messagebox

# Declare global variables
global selectedBackground
global selectedForeground

selectedBackground="white"
selectedForeground="red"

# Tk() helps to display the root window and manages all the other components of the tkinter application and assigns it to root.
root = Tk()
root.eval("tk::PlaceWindow . center")
root.configure(bg=selectedBackground)

cipherButton = Button(root, text="  Cipher  ", padx=40, pady=20, command=openCipher, borderwidth=0, fg="#22fd35", bg="black", highlightbackground="#22fd35").grid(row=1, column=0)
decipherButton = Button(root, text="Decipher", padx=40, pady=20, command=openDecipher, borderwidth=0, fg="#22fd35", bg="black", highlightbackground="#22fd35").grid(row=1, column=1)
spacer1 = Label(root, text="     ", padx=10, pady=1, background="black").grid(row=4, column=1)
quitButton = Button(root, text="Exit d3cryptt", padx=10, pady=5, command=root.quit, borderwidth=0, fg="#22fd35", bg="black", highlightbackground="#22fd35").grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)
spacer2 = Label(root, text="     ", padx=10, pady=1, background=selectedBackground).grid(row=6, column=1)
changecolour = Button(root, text="change colour", padx=1, pady=5, background="black", command=changeColour).grid(row=7, column=0)

#Enter the event main loop
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried using a function. Something like this.

```
def changeColour():
    selectedBackground="black"
    selectedForeground="#22fd35"


changecolour = Button(root, text="change colour", padx=1, pady=5, background="black", command=changeColour).grid(row=7, column=0)
```

But that doesn't work. I think a function is the right way to go, but I may be wrong.

I will also need this 'theme' to carry on to any other windows that are created from this window. I think I can just do that by using lambda in the command section of the widget.

Comment: Your `changeColour()` function is just setting a couple of local variables - which is completely pointless.  Even if you were setting the existing global variables instead, that wouldn't magically change the color of widgets that were created using a previous value of those variables - you have to explicitly call `.config()` or equivalent method on the widgets to change their color.

Comment: so i would have to have each widget in the function changeColour() and then call .config ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Widget.config(bg=color)` is what your looking for.

Here is a small example of a theme-changing app:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkmacosx import Button

root = Tk()


def changethemetoblack():
    root.config(bg="#000000")


def changethemetowhite():
    root.config(bg="#ffffff")


def changethemetored():
    root.config(bg="#ff0000")


themeblackbutton = Button(root, text="Change Theme To Black", command=changethemetoblack, bg="#000000", fg="#ffffff")
themewhitebutton = Button(root, text="Change Theme To White", command=changethemetowhite)
themeredbutton = Button(root, text="Change Theme To Red", command=changethemetored, bg="#ff0000", fg="#ffffff")

themeblackbutton.pack()
themewhitebutton.pack()
themeredbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I'll try to change it so that it applies for your code.
However, your provided script does not seem to be a working one. I assume this is because it is only a snippet of the real one. I'm not pushing for your entire code, but edit it so we can run it. Ex. `openCipher` method is causing errors as we have not defined it.